# License Distirbution of modified QGIS and Plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, license

My company (public service) developed a modified QGIS and QGIS-Plugins for crisis units. Some of the Plugins are self developed and some of them are modified from already existing QGIS-Plugins. All of them a licensed by GNU.

Our plan is to distribute the Software on a free available Website. So everybody can download the software there. Would this be enough to comply with the GNU/GPL License conditions? Or do we need to share the Software and the Plug-Ins on another platform?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  However, even if you reduce the scope of your question to only one question I think that it is about open source licensing in general rather than GIS so perhaps ask on the [opensource.se] Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: As a rule, legal questions are best asked of your lawyer, not self-selected individuals on the Internet. This will both reduce the likelihood of visiting a courtroom, and of losing, should it come to that.

Comment: @MrXsquared I don't know what causes you to believe that QGIS is licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0. The license is [GPLv2](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/LICENSE).